# Start animation from beginning after scrolling to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page I have certain animation. When I scroll the whole page I want to make sure that animation starts from the beginning, rather then to have already finished animation on my page.
Check this out: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ykto7uu9/49/

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#animation").animate({left: '250px'});
        });
    });
```

```css
html,body {
            height: 100%;
     }
    
    .first {
      background-color: green;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .second {
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .third {
      background-color: red;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .button {
      position: absolute;
      margin-top: 50%;
    }
    
    .animation {
      background:#98bf21;
      height:100px;
      width:100px;
      position:absolute;
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" class="first"></div>
    <div id="second" class="second">
    <button id="button" class="button">Start Animation</button>
    Click on the button Start Animation!<br>
    Now every time I scroll up to green or red div, I want Block to be placed at the first position before animation.
    <div id="animation" class="animation">Block</div>
    </div>
    <div id="third" class="third"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the animation when someone scrolls pass it you need to remove the style attribute of the element like this:

`$('#animation').removeAttr('style')`

[Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yef7cutu/)

Comment: This really works in an example. However I am having issues with real page Im working on. This condition is not recognizable: if ($(document).scrollTop() < $('#section-one').offset().top || $(document).scrollTop() == $('#section-three').offset().top). Any idea on that?

Comment: You maybe should go with $(window) instead, or presenting your real code. What kinds of error du you get?

Comment: Ah, I have switched order of condition, where I had put on first place section-three, then section-one. Now its working!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$("#animation")
    .animate({left: '250px'})
    .animate({left: '0px'});
```

Chain the another animation to reset the block's position

Comment: Thanks. However my example is just a simplified version of my case. I already have something like this and my question refers to something else. So what I want is to make sure that every time I scroll to another div that doesnt contain animation, that animation starts from beginning when I scroll back to the div that contains animation. I think this will include scroll, height methods but I am not able to apply them.

Comment: Then you can keep track of scrolling position of the div that contains animated box and whenever that DIV comes into view either from top or bottom, reset the animated box position.

Answer (score 0):

You have a nice JS lib that does just what you need. Its called smoove.

CSS

```
<style>
html,body {
      height: 100%;
}

.first {
background-color: green;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.second {
background-color: yellow;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.third {
background-color: red;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.button {
position: absolute;
margin-top: 50%;
}

.animation {
background:#98bf21;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
  margin-top: 20%;
  left: 300px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="first" class="first"></div>
<div id="second" class="second">
<button id="button" class="button">Start Animation</button>
Click on the button Start Animation!<br>
Now every time I scroll up to green or red div, I want Block to be placed at the first position before animation.
<div id="animation" class="animation block" data-move-x="-300px">Block</div>
</div>
<div id="third" class="third"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-smoove/0.2.6/jquery.smoove.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.block').smoove({offset:'10%'});
});
</script>
```

Here is a quick example, but you can tweek it your way

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/ykto7uu9/50/)

Answer (score 0):

You must add scroll() on next line for 'window' selector.
Here's your solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#animation").animate({left: '250px'});
});
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("#animation").css({left: '10px'});
});
```

});